# How to transform part of a string in a JSON?

Tags: java, json, string

I have a string with a URL and some other text in "JSON format". Like this:

`String result = "https://somesite.com/generic-url/11 {'id':11,'checked':true,'geo':'0'}"`

I know that it's weird...but I have to discard the URL from the string and convert the remaining data to a JSONObject.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of converting the JSON to a JSONObject, there are several libraries available, two that I've commonly used are Google's GSON [library](https://github.com/google/gson)  and [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)

In terms of extracting the JSON from the string, you could use a regular expression to grab the first '{' and everything after it as part of a capture group, I expect that will work. Something like `^[^\{]*(.+)` may work in your case.

As an example, with GSON:

```
Pattern jsonPattern = Pattern.compile("^[^\\{]*(.+)");
Matcher jsonMatcher = jsonPattern.matcher(result);
if (jsonMatcher.find())
{
   String json = jsonMatcher.group(0);
   JSONObject jsonObj = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
}
else
{
   // Log that match was not found for result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    final String regex = ".*(\\{.*\\}$)";
    final String string = "https://somesite.com/generic-url/11 {\"id\":11,\"checked\":true,\"geo\":\"0\"}";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    matcher.find();
    String json = matcher.group(1);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using [Regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and [JSON.org](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813)?

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String line = "https://somesite.com/generic-url/11 {'id':11,'checked':true,'geo':'0'}"; 
        String pattern = "\\{.*\\}$";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

        if (m.find()) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(m.group(0));
            System.out.println(json);
            System.out.println(json.getLong("id"));
            System.out.println(json.getBoolean("checked"));
            System.out.println(json.getInt("geo"));
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
{"geo":"0","checked":true,"id":11}
11
true
0
```